# PowerShell registry permission on new computer

Tags: powershell

I am trying to set up new computers and as it is a new computer it won't allow me to run the PowerShell script as admin. As I can't run it as administrator I can't REG ADD my AutoAdminLogon, DefaultUserName and DefaultPassword. How can I work around this to get my script to allow this and run as admin.

```
Add-Content -Path "C:\Install Logs\Install.log" -Value "Set up auto login as admin - $(Get-Date)"
REG ADD "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v AutoAdminLogon /t REG_SZ /d 1 /f
REG ADD "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v DefaultUserName /t REG_SZ /d AdminIT /f
REG ADD "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v DefaultPassword /t REG_SZ /d Password /f
```

Comment: _it won't allow me to run the PowerShell script as admin_.. How? Anything to do with [Execution Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies)

Comment: No, I believe it's because its a laptop with one login and no admin setup. The problem is, I don't want to create an admin account for each laptop yet as that gets done  in Active Directory when in use. All I want to do is run it with the privilege's so I can add the Reg Keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only work around so far that I have found is to make a .bat file and in that force the PowerShell script to run as Admin.

```
PowerShell.exe -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%~dpn0.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}"
```